# Can anyone help me find out more information about the Daniels and Fisher Cadets?

Tags: 20th-century, 1900s, colorado

According to [Colorado Encyclopedia Online](https://coloradoencyclopedia.org/article/daniels-and-fisher-tower), William B. Daniels opened a dry goods store when he arrived in Denver, CO in 1864. In 1872 he partnered with William G. Fisher to make Daniels and Fisher Co. I had heard of this company before, there's still an historic marker on their tower in Denver.

What was new was when I came across the following photo in the book [*Historic Photos of Denver*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1596523190):

[image: Daniels and Fisher Cadets train on the roof of their store.]

The only information contained on that page that is not shown in the picture is that this is numbered page 82. There are no other mentions of the cadets in the book, but the store is mentioned a few other times. Taking this picture and caption at face value, I took this to mean that these young boys were undergoing military training so that they could be armed guards for merchandise from the store.

However, the only other mention I could find of them on Google MAY dispute that conclusion. Mark Barnhouse's [*Daniels and Fisher: Denver's Best Place to Shop*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Daniels_and_Fisher/f9dCCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Daniels+and+Fisher+Cadets%22&pg=PT45&printsec=frontcover) includes a brief mention of the cadets, saying:

> Inspired by his war experiences, Daniels decided in 1902 that his young male employees would benefit from military training and so created the Daniels and Fisher Cadets. Wearing dark blue uniforms, the twenty-one boys, mostly fourteen or fifteen years old, drilled with real weapons on the store's roof and were said to handle them "like veterans." They marched in parades and appeared at other public events.

That is the entire mention of the cadets. Immediately following that, in the same paragraph, Daniels's patriotism is on display literally, as they talk about the largest American flag at the time being hung from the store. And, there is no other mention of cadet in the preview available on Google, or possibly it searched the whole book, IDK. Either way, the way this is worded leaves me to believe the military drilling was kind of non-functional. In this description, these cadets are made out to be a boy scout type of institution. Overall, however, I am not sure what to make of these two sources.

By searching "Fisher cadet", on the [*Colorado Historic Newspapers Collection*](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/?a=q&hs=1&r=1&results=1&txq=%22Fisher+cadet%22&t=0&dafdq=&dafmq=&dafyq=1859&datdq=&datmq=&datyq=2022&txf=txIN%7CtxCO%7CtxTA&ssnip=img&ccq=&ciq=&puq=&oa=&e=31-07-1941-31-12-1941--en-20--61-byDA-img-txIN%7CtxCO%7CtxTA-%22Lewis%22-------0------) (which is the best statewide, free newspaper access, I have yet found) I get two hits, only one of which was relevant. The first mention is in a [31 May 1901 edition of *The Rocky Mountain News*](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/?a=d&d=RMD19010531-01.2.3&srpos=1&e=--1859---2022--en-20--1-byDA-img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22Fisher+cadet%22-------0------). In this mention, the cadets are marching in a parade honoring Civil War veterans. The entirety of the mention of the cadets says:

> Thirty-two cadets from Daniels & Fisher's store, in brown khaki uniforms and small muskets, made a creditable appearance and displayed marked proficiency in the art of drilling. Their three nights a week of training is evident. They were in charge of Captain Charles Leonard and Lieutenant A.S. Gibbons.

The D&F cadets distinguish themselves from other boy soldiers by having real muskets and drilling thrice weekly. While this does lend credence to the boyscout aspect of the group, it says nothing about whether this military training is used to teach the boys how to defend merchandise. Also of note is that this third source obviously contradicts the second on that said the cadets were started the year after this one. Further, I could find no relevant hits on Newspapers.com or NewspaperArchive.com (which you may have free access at home through your public library, so check that out if you are interested).

My hope is that someone can find an online secondary source providing more clarity on whether or not the boys provided armed protection for the merchandise. It could even be the case, it is a mix of guarding and non-guarding, like, maybe only one or two boys provide protection while the other boys carry merchandise. Can anyone provide any more details? Thank you.

Comment: They could still be drilling, with weapons, but not be expected to actually guard anything for the store.

Comment: https://denverhistory.blog/2018/06/18/pioneer-monument-subscribers-4-8/ Has a mention, including activities for girls as well.

Comment: @JonCuster I do not discount that possibility. And, thanks for that tidbit. Doesn't help much, though.